# Add CSS classes to theme function

Tags: 7, theming

I'm implementing `hook_theme()` in a custom module.

```php
function monitor_chart_theme() {
  return array(
    'chart_monitor' => array(
      'template' => 'monitor_chart',
      'variables' => array(
        'container' => null,
        'theme' => null,
        'classes' => null,
        'chart' => null,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

On the template file, I would like to add additional CSS classes the theme function gets in its parameters.
I declared a preprocess function with the following code.

```php
function monitor_chart_preprocess_chart_monitor(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['classes']) {
    foreach ($vars['classes'] as $class) {
      $vars['classes_array'][] = $class;
    }
  }
}
```

The template file contains the following code.

```php
<div id="<?php print $container; ?>" class="<?php print $classes; ?>"></div>
```

If I don't use the preprocess function, the *class* attribute of `<div>` contains just `'chart-monitor'`, the name of the theme function.

Is there a more elegant way to pass extra variables to a template file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, arguments can be passed when calling the theme function:

```
$tpl_data = array(
    'data1' => $data1,
    'data2' => $data2,
);

return theme('my_theme', $tpl_data);
```

Then in the template $data1 and $data2 will be available.

To add a variable passed here to the default drupal class variable in the template we could add the line:

```
$class .= " $data1";
```

before the $class variable is printed.

However I think it's questionable  whether or not this method is preferable to your original.

Comment: This is ok, but if on my tpl I cant print $data1 in "class" attribute, because "class" attribute as the default value, the name of my function (I've updated the post)

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I quite understand what your trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to add a custom class to default one used Drupal, which is *chart-monitor*. The preprocess method works, but I don't know if there is a better way.

Comment: I've updated my answer but I not convinced it's the best way to do it. Sorry I couldn't help more...

Comment: I've already try it, it doesn't work. The attribute "class" of my tpl is simply ignored :( Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only way to pass values to a template file used for a theme function is adding them to the array passed as second argument of `theme()`. In the case of that *chart_monitor* theme function, `theme('chart_monitor', array('classes' => array('new_chart_class')));` would add *new_chart_class* to the CSS classes.

`monitor_chart_preprocess_chart_monitor()` doesn't need a `foreach()` loop.

```php
function monitor_chart_preprocess_chart_monitor(&$vars) {
  if (is_array($vars['classes']) && !empty($vars['classes'])) {
    $vars['classes_array'] = array_merge($vars['classes_array'], $vars['classes']);
  }
}
```

As side note, *chart_monitor* is the CSS class added by [`template_preprocess()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess/7.x) which is called for every theme function for which preprocess functions aren't disabled.

```php
// Initialize html class attribute for the current hook.
$variables['classes_array'] = array(
  drupal_html_class($hook),
);
```

[`template_process()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_process/7.x) then initializes the `$classes` variable a template file gets.

```php
// Flatten out classes.
$variables['classes'] = implode(' ', $variables['classes_array']);
```